# module java.base does not "opens java.net" to unnamed module @3f191845

Tags: android, android-studio

I am completely new to android studio.

After install it and android sdk v4 too . Bellow error shown in android studio :
[image]

I was searched it in google and nothing cant help me . (even I cant download new sdk)

How can i fix it?